# Blanket "immediate" data binding+validation

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, validation

I have a fairly routine setup with some check boxes and numeric up/downs bound to a data class through a BindingSource. The default behaviour seems to be that nothing is updated or validated until the control loses focus, and for this application that's useless. Is there some way to make it such that every single blessed control on that form validates and updates immediately after any change, instead of on focus loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Advance Databindings** properties of your control, Go to on binding property(like Text for TextBox) and on (Data Source Update Model)combo, Select **OnPropertyChange** instead of OnValidation.

Comment: Yep that's him, bear in mind that all changes will fire a change event though, e.g. each key press in a text box. Might not cause a problem, depends on how much business logic whatever you are bound to does.

Comment: Useful, but it only answers half of my question. Instead of going into the binding properties of every control manually, how can I make this the default?

Comment: A dangerous way: press ctrl+H and replace all system.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnValidation with System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged in your solution!!

Comment: Haha, yes, that's on the dangerous side.